# JavaScript - Validate Integer and accept dot, comma

Tags: javascript

I have `price` variable and which can contain:

```
USD12.34 
USD12,34
12,34
23.34
```

Now the output should be -

```
USD12.34 - false
USD12,34 - false
12,34 - true
23.34 - true
```

Now, Using JavaScript I want to validate above data as integer which should accept `dot` and `comma`.

I got this code but no luck:

```
const test = /^\d*(,\d{3})*(\.,\d*)?$/.test( price );
console.log(  ( test ) );
```

Comment: replace comma with dot?

Comment: I dont want to replace, I want accept comma and dot.

Comment: I have updated my question, can you please check it?

Comment: `/^\d+([,.]\d+)?$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = [
  'USD12.34',
  'USD12,34',
  '12,34',
  '23.34',
  '12;34'
].forEach(price => {
  const test = /^\d*(?:[.,]\d+)?$/.test(price);
  console.log(price + ' => ' + test);
});
```

Output:

```
USD12.34 => false
USD12,34 => false
12,34 => true
23.34 => true
12;34 => false
```

Explanation:

- `^` -- anchor at start
- `\d+` -- 1+ digits
- `(?:` -- non-capture group start
- `[.,]` -- a dot or comma
- `\d+` -- 1+ digits
- `)` -- non-capture group end
- `?` -- make non-capture group optional
- `$` -- anchor at end

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example replacing comma with a dot:

```js
// Number with comma rather than decimal:
const numberWithComma = "12000,12";

// Replace commas with decimals and convert to float:
const newNumber = parseFloat(numberWithComma.split(",").join("."));

// Check if number is finite:
const res = Number.isFinite(newNumber);

console.log(res) // true
```

**UPDATE:**
This next example doesn't use regex, but assuming the limitations you've provided in your updated question, it accomplishes what you're after:

```js
// Function to test number:
const testNumber = (value) => {

  // Declare new variable to hold test value after it is parsed:
  let numberToTest;

  // Test value and assign to numberToTest:
  if (typeof value === "number") {
    numberToTest = value
  } else if (value.startsWith("USD")) {
    const temp = value.split("USD")[1]
    numberToTest = temp.includes(",") ? parseFloat(temp.split(",").join(".")) : parseFloat(temp)
  } else if (value.includes(",")) {
    numberToTest = parseFloat(value.split(",").join("."))
  } else {
    numberToTest = parseFloat(value)
  }

// Test is number is finite and return the boolean:
return Number.isFinite(numberToTest);
}
```

Comment: I dont want to replace, I want accept comma and dot.

Comment: Note this only works if the commas in your dataset are for decimal places, fails if commas are used a separators.

Comment: If you'd like to accept both, you'll have to parse the content in one manner or another - are the commas being used as thousands separators or for decimal points?

Comment: I have updated my question, can you please check it?

Comment: I've updated my answer for you, not a regex solution but it achieves what you're after.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but maybe i couldn't tell you my exact need. Can you again check my updated question?

Comment: No problems, I tested that function I added against the sample cases and it works on all.
You'd just run it against reach price like: `const res = testNumber(price)`. Will return `true` or `false`